# get content between tags include inner tags

Tags: php, html

I have the content:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="another div">
        other content
    </div>
    <div class="fck_detail width_common">
        <p class="Normal">
            Some text 1.
        </p>
        <p class="Normal">
            Some text 2.
        </p>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="embed-container">
                <div id="video-18574" data-component="true" data-component-type="video" data-component-value="18574" data-component-typevideo="2"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="Normal">
            Some text 3.
        </p>
        <p class="Normal">
            Some text 4.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I use the function below to get content of 'div class="fck_detail width_common"'

```
function get_content_by_tag($content, $tag_and_more, $include_tag = true){
        $p = stripos($content,$tag_and_more,0);
        if($p==false) return "";
        $content=substr($content,$p);
        $p = stripos($content," ",0);
        if(abs($p)==0) return "";
        $open_tag = substr($content,0,$p);
        $close_tag = substr($open_tag,0,1)."/".substr($open_tag,1).">";

        $count_inner_tag = 0;
        $p_open_inner_tag = 1; 
        $p_close_inner_tag = 0;
        $count=1;
        do{
            $p_open_inner_tag = stripos($content,$open_tag,$p_open_inner_tag);
            $p_close_inner_tag = stripos($content,$close_tag,$p_close_inner_tag);
            $count++;
            if($p_close_inner_tag!=false) $p = $p_close_inner_tag;
            if($p_open_inner_tag!=false){
                if(abs($p_open_inner_tag)<abs($p_close_inner_tag)){
                    $count_inner_tag++;
                    $p_open_inner_tag++;
                }else{
                    $count_inner_tag--;
                    $p_close_inner_tag++;
                }
            }else{
                $count_inner_tag--;
                if($p_close_inner_tag>0) $p_close_inner_tag++;
            }
        }while($count_inner_tag>0);
        if($include_tag)
            return substr($content,0,$p+strlen($close_tag));
        else{
            $content = substr($content,0,$p);
            $p = stripos($content,">",0);
            return substr($content,$p+1);
        }
    }
```

then I try

```
echo get_content_by_tag($content, '<div class="fck_detail width_common">');
```

It only return:

```
<div class="fck_detail width_common">
    <p class="Normal">
        Some text 1.
    </p>
    <p class="Normal">
        Some text 2.
    </p>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <div class="embed-container">
            <div id="video-18574" data-component="true" data-component-type="video" data-component-value="18574" data-component-typevideo="2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

missing the DIV with content "some text 3" and "some text 4"

who can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The whole solution is wrong. Try php DOM extension instead.

Comment: can give me a sample?

Comment: have you ever heard of http://php.net and http://google.com?

Comment: are u mocking me?
if u don't know, please don't say.

Comment: I tried DOM, but can't get content, if it has inner tag

Comment: I'm using [this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for all these kinds of stuff. I like it's jquery approach.

Comment: vlzvl ninja'd me on the answer!  Just thought I'd add: the reason zerkms said your solution was all wrong is that you really shouldn't use basic string functions to work with HTML in any significant way.  HTML (and XML for that matter) is complex and you're setting yourself up for trouble.  You should use proper parsers like simplehtmldom or DOMDocument.  And if you ever think to use regular expressions to match HTML: Don't do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is through [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net)

```
$str = '
<html>
<body>
    <div class="another div">
        other content
    </div>
    <div class="fck_detail width_common">
        <p class="Normal">
            Some text 1.
        </p>
        <p class="Normal">
            Some text 2.
        </p>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="embed-container">
                <div id="video-18574" data-component="true" data-component-    type="video" data-component-value="18574" data-component-typevideo="2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="Normal">
        Some text 3.
    </p>
    <p class="Normal">
        Some text 4.
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html> 
';

$html = str_get_html($str);
echo $html->find("div[class='fck_detail width_common']",0)->innertext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library : http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

You can get your data in the following way

```
$url="www.yoururl.html";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html($url);
$data = $html->find('.fck_detail',0);
```

or

```
$html = str_get_html($str);
$data = $html->find("div[class='fck_detail width_common']",0)->innertext;
```